# GLM: Warning message: 'newdata' had 16623 rows but variables found have 22488 rows

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm

I have scoured the forum far and wide and found many articles like this, however, none that solved my issue.

Now, I turn to you.

I have data similar to this:

```
ontime currency incoterms price month
1      USD      FOB       234.2    01
1      CAD      FOB        92.4    01
0      USD      DAP       238.9    02
0      EUR      FOB       100      03
1      CNY      DAP       739.8    04
```

I this code:

```
g = df$ontime      #binary
a = df$currency    #String
b = df$INCOTERMS   #String
c = df$price       #float
f = df$month       #string

mod1 <- glm(g~a+b+c,family=binomial(link="logit"), data=df[f=="01",])
pred_ontime1 <- predict(mod1,df[f%in%c("02","03","04"),],type="response")
```

My desire is to test my model, that I trained on data from month 01, on month 02, 03 and 04.

My outcome, however is this:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 16623 rows but variables found have 22488 rows
```

I have tried training on month 01 and testing on 01,02,03 and 04, which did not give me the error message, however, it seems inappropriate to test on data included in my training set.

The value 16623 is of course the combined number of rows in 02, 03 and 04, while 22488 is the combined number of rows in 01, 02, 03 and 04.

What can I do?

Comment: what is `pur8`?

Comment: Hi Christian- can you provide a subset of your real data such that someone could reproduce this error message? This would be the first step towards solving this problem.

Comment: @jchaykow the name of my dataframe. Corrected.

Comment: Maybe `f` got changed? Or there's recycling? Use the column `month`  from your `df`: `df[df$month %in% c("02","03","04"),]`, not some `f` from your environment (for both the model and the prediction).

Comment: @colin I have provided so now.

Comment: @Gregor I actually defined my variables as a,b,c etc for posting on this site, as I thought it would give a better overview. In my program I have both these variables and a version with the column names. Both provide the same error.

Comment: Well, that would break things even if it was already working. Your model is defined in terms of variables named `a`, `b`, and `c`. So when you predict on new data, it is looking inside the data frame you give to `newdata` for columns named `a`, `b`, and `c`. But those are not your column names. Instead, use your column names in the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the model without saving each column to a vector first. I think `predict()` can't tell that it is the same variable names as it modeled on.

```
mod1 <- glm(ontime ~ currency + INCOTERMS + price, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df[df$month == "01",])
pred_ontime1 <- predict(mod1,df[df$month %in% c("02","03","04"),], type = "response")
```

See if that works.

---

Here is a reproducible example for anyone interested:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("ontime currency incoterms price month
0      USD      DAP       234.2    01
                          1      CAD      FOB        92.4    01
                          0      USD      DAP       238.9    02
                          0      USD      FOB       100      03
                          1      CAD      DAP       739.8    04"), header = TRUE)

mod1 <- glm(ontime ~ currency + incoterms + price, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df[df$month == 1,])
pred_ontime1 <- predict(mod1, df[df$month %in% c(2:4),], type = "response")
pred_ontime1
           3            4            5 
5.826215e-11 5.826215e-11 1.000000e+00
```

Comment: For some reason, this worked now. I had done this (at least I thought so) a million times while ripping my hair apart in frustration. 

Lesson learned: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here I have generated some pseudo dat that look like your problem as the data frame `df`:

```
currency <- c('USD','CAD','CAD','EUR','CNY','USD','EUR','CNY')
incoterms <- c('FOB','FOB','DAP','DAP','FOB','DAP','FOB','DAP')
month <- c('01','01','01','01','01','02','03','04')
df <- data.frame(currency, incoterms, month)
df <- rbind(df,df,df,df)
df$price <- rnorm(nrow(df), 200, 50)
df$ontime <- rbinom(nrow(df), 1, 0.5)
```

I then go ahead and fit `mod1`. Importantly, I don't define each predictor as a vector, I just pull them by name from the data frame, which has been subsetted to only include the first month.

```
mod1 <- glm(ontime ~ currency + incoterms + price, data = df[month == '01',])
```

The following predict function now runs fine:

```
pred <- predict(mod1, df[month %in% c('02','03','04'),], type = 'response')
```